# How to express "thanks" when I am made to do something

Tags: word-choice

How does one express thanks when made to do something. For example:

Thanks for making me realize the meaning of happiness - 幸せの意味を気づかせて（くれて）ありがとう

To me, it doesn't sound right because I feel that 気づかせて really means "making me realize (against my will)". Is there a better way of saying this?

Comment: *I feel that 気づかせて really means "making me realize (against my will)"* -- why do you feel so?

Comment: "Thanks for making me realize the meaning of happiness" - I don't understand what that means even in English.

Comment: @macraf causation means to "make someone" do something. Somehow gives me the impression it's forced. Is it not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

幸せの意味を気づかせてくれてありがとう is a perfectly natural sentence and it makes perfect sense. Note that くれて is mandatory even in non-causative sentence; お皿を洗ってくれてありがとう is fine but お皿を洗ってありがとう is not.

Japanese causative form (せる/させる) is not always forcible, and it can be translated to "to make someone do ～", "to let someone do ～" or "to allow someone to do ～". Examples of non-forcible せる/させる:

- 大学に行かせてください。
  Please allow me to go to the university.
- 子供に夜中までゲームをさせてしまった。
  I allowed my kid to play games until late at night (and it was my fault).
- 彼には好きなことを言わせておけ。
  Let him say whatever he wants.
- 眠そうだったから、そのまま寝させておこう。
  She looked sleepy, so let her keep sleeping.
- 妻を事故で死なせてしまった。
  My wife was killed in an accident (and it was my fault).

Comment: Thanks. Without くれて, what would the sentence translate to? Or would it just be grammatically wrong and it wouldn't make sense without the くれて?

Comment: @Newbie Without くれて, the sentence is simply ungrammatical. Proper use of donatory verbs is very important in Japanese. Of course you can say ～ていただいてありがとうございます instead, which is much politer.